# How to recover original thumbnail of an edited image?

Tags: metadata, jpeg, thumbnail-preview

I would like to know if it is possible to recover the original version of an edited picture.

The metadata of the picture in question indicates . "Hasthumbnail  : False".

So how is it possible to recover the original thumbnail (Hasthumbnail : True) of that edited picture?

I really need to recover that original picture.

Answer (score 2):

No. You can't do that. Where would it come from?

In any case, the JPEG thumbnail is just a very small tiny version, usually [160×120](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/25820/why-are-my-recovered-images-only-160x120-pixels). That's so small as to be basically useless, so it's often discarded so as to not waste that space and/or bandwidth. Once it's discarded, you could create a *new* one from the full-sized image, but you can't in any way create one from a *different* image which you don't have. JPEG files do not store history.

Comment: Ok.
Thanks for your answer.
But is it then possible to recoverthe original image instead of its thumbnail ?

Thanks.

Comment: No — there is no history or undo information saved. This is one reason people use tools like Lightroom for photo editing, because instead of actually overwriting the JPEG, they store a list of edits to be made and generate a completely separate file on export.